# Config RADIUS server to authenticate VPN server?

Tags: networking, radius

I am implementing this project on linux but can't link VPN server and RADIUS server. I has configured already RADIUS client, on VPN server has choose RADIUS authentication but no working. Help me!

This is my topology [Here](http://blog.yimg.com/1/xIcK4oZ7s5.hv1ISKZkkxzLxIQEmGzyG.gFFyNoHdn.fYxBgrn9Mfw--/8/l/4tVtaDbNfu0bPh8PG4ZV_g.jpg)

VPN srv:

- eth0 (10.0.0.1) connect internet.
- eth1 (172.16.0.1) connect LAN (RADIUS srv in LAN)

  RADIUS srv: (172.16.0.2)

RADIUS server using freeradius soft, openVPN for VPNsrv

- I had join a user "A" in */etc/raddb/users.*
- Create client in /etc/raddb/clients.conf like following
     client 192.168.1.200 {
       secret ...
      shortname ...
    }
- And VPN srv using openVPN, i has enable RADIUS authentication and enter IP *172.16.0.2.*
- In RADIUS srv, i test with cmd: ***radtest A 123 172.16.0.2 0 "secret"*** but unsuccessful.
  I dont know that that configuring is not enough allready yet? And how do the way test?

Comment: which VPN? You need to configure VPN to use RADIUS for AAA. Have you done that? if you give more details, then it will be easy to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for this! I am update more info. I also enable AAA on openVPN but it dont work still!

Comment: thanks for updating your question. I have given an answer, which might help. you need to try a series of things out. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

from your description, it looks like your RADIUS configuration needs to be fixed. Unless the "radtest" works, it won't work with openVPN.

So, how do you find what the problem is?

What you can do is:
1. start the server in debug mode, radiusd -X.
2. run  radtest A 123 172.16.0.2 0 "secret" 
3. check the debug logs, it will show why the authentication is failing.

I would suggest you do as this (http://freeradius.org/doc/) document says. Create a user with exact same information as used in the document for testing first. If that works, create your own real user.

Another thing that I am doubting, might be wrong is your users file. Check the man page for users on your Radius server using "man users".

The users file resides in the RADIUS database directory, by default /etc/raddb. It contains a series of configuration directives which are used by the files module to decide how to authorize and authenticate each user request.

Check this sample file as well, might give a clue what is wrong in your setup. http://docs.snake.de/TNT/7/radius/userfile.htm

Comment: Once more, i thank you for your helping. I am also doubting that problem start in RADIUS server, they can be user file or cliens file. I'll try again.

Comment: This is all that show after i use "radtest": <br/>
Re-sending Access-Request of id 181 to 192.168.1.111 port 1812
        User-Name = "sali"
        User-Password = "123"
        NAS-IP-Address = 255.255.255.255
        NAS-Port = 0
radclient: no response from server for ID 181

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are missing the Message-Authenticator attribute in your response, and your RADIUS server is probably requiring this.

You can check it by creating a free account on Cloudessa RADIUS (Google for it). Choose PAP as an authentication method. Then try authenticating and see if this works. If not, see what is the error message in the Logs panel.